# Function not executing when called second time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a project where I take inputs from a html form and submit them inside of google sheets. Its working fine with no errors. So I wanted to add a function where the user can resubmit the data incase of server-side error.
The issue is when I am calling the same function which submits the data(working) it doesnt seem to respond. I am sending the same array of data yet it doesnt return any server response. If I refresh the entire page it works again, its just that it wont let me run the same function twice in one session.
Here are the codes I used:

Html:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).withFailureHandler(onFailure).addRecord(rows);
```

GAS:

```
function doGet(request) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
 }
//division,block,ward,booth,committee,designation,name,phone,email
function addRecord(rows) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/-myProjectID-/edit#gid=0';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("FORM DATA");
  var row = rows.length;
  var column = rows[0].length;

 //LockService.getScriptLock.waitLock(10000);
 // var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
 // lock.waitLock(10000);    //prevent creating 2 sessions simultaneously

 try {
  webAppSheet.getRange(webAppSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, row, column).setValues(rows);
  // lock.releaseLock();
  return "Ok"
  } catch (ex) {
    lock.releaseLock();
    return "Error"
 }
}

function getScriptURL() {
  return ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 }
```

to retry i run the same function "addRecord()" and pass the same array"rows[]".
Can anyone point out where I am doing wrong or is it some special attribute in GAS that prevents me from doing otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
gs:

function addRecord(rows) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(myProjectId);
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("FORM DATA");
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValues(rows);
  return "Ok"
}

js:

function dontknowname() {
  //disable send button here
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(() => 'enable send button here')
    .addRecords(rows);
}
```

Comment: the "google.script.return" doesnt seem to work for me. Why cant I use use "script.run" here? any particular reason?

Comment: Sorry ...don't know why I typed return

Comment: That should keep the user from saving another one until you get a return from the first.

Comment: Well I am using ScriptLock for duplicate entries. Anyway my question is different, the same function is not running twice, it would be helpful if you could guide me on why so its happening.

Comment: Hey, just solved the issue myself, the array variable i was passing wasnt declared globally lol. Its working perfect now! thanks man for the help! :) I will mark your answer as correct!  :)